# Can "there is" be omitted in the sentence "Where there is no intention involved, there is no lying involved."?

Tags: grammar

Can we change the sentence

> Where there is no intention involved, there is no lying involved.

to

> Where no intention involved, no lying involved.

or more concisely to

> No intention involved, no lying involved.

Generally speaking, where, if at all, can "there is" and similar verbs be omitted?

Comment: Neither of your alternatives are complete sentences. You could change it to "Where no intention is involved, no lying is involved."

Comment: What Katherine said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two possible meanings of "sentence":

(1) a well-formed grammatical expression that includes at least a verb and (if not an imperative expression) a subject

(2) a natural and coherent expression that in writing starts with a capital letter and ends with a period, question mark, or exclamation mark, and in speech has a characteristic pattern of intonation

Definition 1 requires a verb, so, clearly, omitting "there is" from your examples would not lead to a valid definition-1 sentence.

Definition 2, which is more informal, allows for **ellipsis** (omission) of words as long as the result is still natural and coherent. A common example: "No pain, no gain." However, your first specific example "Where no intention involved, no lying involved" would certainly fail the "natural and coherent" test, and your second example "No intention involved, no lying involved" would fail according to most native speakers' standards as well. Few native speakers would use a sequence of words this long and awkward without verbs. Thus, both of your examples would probably be rejected as a sentence according to both definition 1 and definition 2.

Comment: What about "No intention, no lying", on a par with "no pain, no gain"?

Comment: "No pain, no gain" has something going for it: as a result of being short and catchy, it has become common, so even though it doesn't have a verb or any connecting words, people are familiar with how it's used. "No intention, no lying" doesn't have those advantages, so a speaker would have to rely heavily on context to clarify its meaning. I'm curious about your motive in asking the question. Are you trying to understand how English works by analyzing an edge case? Or are you trying to come up with a particular way to phrase something that has a high probability of being understood?

Comment: I would upvote this as the superior answer but for two things: (1) I don't think “informal” is a good word to describe definition 2, as there is nothing more or less formal about it; it's just a different definition. And (2) I disagree that “No intention involved, no lying involved” is too long to sound natural to most native speakers. It certainly sounds perfectly natural and coherent to me, especially since the verb is the same one repeated.

Answer (score 1):

Your second sentence really doesn't work, it reads choppily and there's no verb.  The third option, "no intention involved, no lying involved" can kinda work - it isn't a grammatically complete sentence since it doesn't have a verb, but it will make sense with an assumed "is", and it makes a pithy short phrase which sounds workable.

Perhaps it is because the latter construction has a rhythm to it, and it is obviously pared down to the basics so no extras are expected if they can be assumed.  On the other hand, adding "where" as in the second sentence tends to focus the attention on the missing verb, because it otherwise has everything it needs.

Or you could use a different verb, like "means", so "no intention involved, means no lying involved" which does successfully omit the "there is", but remains a complete sentence.  You could take or leave the use of "where" in this construction.

So, while the "there" can be dropped with only minimal rearrangement of the sentence, the "is" has to be replaced by another verb to be grammatical, or else pared down from a sentence to a phrase - or quote - where the completeness is not assumed, in which case the sentence can work with an implied "is".